# I installed NetBeans 8.2 and can't change UI language. I didn't find any option for it. Any suggestions?

Tags: netbeans

I installed NetBeans 8.2 and can't change hte UI language. I didn't find any option for it. Any suggestions?
I use this process but it is not working

- Find netbeans etc, likely at the C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.2\etc
- Open netbeans.conf
- Find netbeans_default_options
- Add those options, so: netbeans_default_options="blablabla - J-Duser.language=en -J-Duser.region=US"
- Save file
- Restart/start netbeans.
  [image: image description here]

Comment: please help me how to solve this issue

Answer (score 7):

You need to add:

```
--locale en_US
```

Instead of:

```
J-Duser.language=en -J-Duser.region=US
```

Example:

```
netbeans_default_options="-J-client --locale en_US"
```